# Craft Commerce and Worldpay not marking payments as complete

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, worldpay

I'm working on a Craft Commerce 1.2.1331 site using Worldpay but I'm having problems with Worldpay test transactions not completing the order first-time.

Users are redirected from Worldpay to the Order Thank You template but the order is not being marked as Complete. It remains an active cart. Then, if you checkout again, the order is marked as complete and the cart is emptied. Anyone?

There's nothing in the logs. Actually, there isn't a Commerce log.

Comment: you could send an email to craft commerce support with your question, maybe you get more help from them.

Comment: Already have. I'm posting it here in case anyone else has seen this.